# Trying to select data between middle of two years and months

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select data between july 2017 to jun 2018 using sql query but not getting expected output. Let's say m having data from jan 2017 up to dec 2018,
and i want to select data between july 2017 to jun 2018. how can I achieve this?

[image]

This is the data i'm having

And Expected Output is

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you've tried using unsucessfully? We can help you from there.

Comment: Please provide the query you are using so far

Comment: And sample data and desired results!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Month, `Year`
FROM master_table
WHERE Year BETWEEN 2017 AND 2018 AND MonthIndex BETWEEN 1 AND 12 ORDER BY MonthIndex; this is the query m using but its selecting all months from 2017 to 2018

Comment: I want output from july 2017 to june 2018 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MySQL STR_TO_DATE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM <YOUR TABLE> WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ',`Month`,' ',`Year`), '%d %M %Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('1 Jun 2017', '%d %b %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31 Jul 2017', '%d %b %Y');
```

Comment: I'm not having date

Comment: @anjali if you don't have date then you can set date initially 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM master_table WHERE Month
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('July 2017', '%b %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('June 2018', '%b %Y')  it returns null

Comment: What are you having? What's the format of the date? If your column is in varchar then convert it to date.

Comment: @farhana what to set for date column then?

Comment: @anjalijibhakate if your months are in full then use `%M` for the month.

Comment: @cdaiga m only having seperate month and year column

Comment: Add a sample and expected data to your question.

Comment: @cdaiga i have attached the image of sample data m having

Comment: @cdaiga thank you so much. I got the expected output.. :)